# MYSQL Join three tables and group by joined date

Tags: mysql, join

I am a MySQL beginner so please be patient with me!

I have three tables

1-Order

```
Order Id | Order Date
```

2-users

```
user Id | Registration date
```

3-connection

```
user Id | Order ID
```

I am trying to calculate conversion rate grouped by date 
The conversion rate, example, 300 users registered in January 2013, and 100 of them made one or more purchases, the conversion rate of the registered user to purchaser is 33%

so the final output should be

table

```
date    | number of registered users | number of orders | Conversion rate  

Jan-2011|            300             |         100      |     33%
```

many thanks for the help!

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: YOu say `Jan 2013` in your question but `jan-2011` in your desired results. Is that a type or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @JNevill its a typo, I just gave an example of the data and how to calculate conversion rate

Comment: @ernesthm I am trying atm, but nothing is working so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is that you need:

```
select u.registrationDate as date, 
       count(distinct u.id) as number_of_registered_users,
       count(distinct o.id) as number_of_orders,
       round(count(distinct o.id)/count(distinct u.id)*100) as conversion_rate
from users u 
left join `Order` o on u.registrationDate = o.orderDate 
left join connection c on c.orderId = o.id and c.usersId = u.id
group by u.registrationDate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3fa10/6/0).

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it is showing me per day, I want it to show me just per month and year, can you please help me with that??

Comment: Thank you i figured it out  DATE_FORMAT(u.date_registered, "%y-%m")